# Operaciones aritméticas con métodos byte

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de emplear como base para operaciones aritméticas el valor recogido en un método `public static byte` de la siguiente forma (el valor de `unitaryPrice` está asignado previamente):

```
public class Cocacola {
    private static String name = "Cocacola";
    public static byte unitaryPrice = 2;
    private static byte amountForDiscount = 4;
    private static byte discount = 6;

public static String getName(){
    return name;}
public static byte getUnitaryPrice(){
    return unitaryPrice;}
public static byte getAmountForDiscount(){
    return amountForDiscount;}
public static byte getDiscount() {
    return discount;

switch (cantidad) {
    case 1:
        getUnitaryPrice();
        break; //En esta opción no me da error
    case 2:
    {...}
    case 8: ;
        break;
}
```

He probado diferentes opciones:
    `return unitaryPrice*2`
    `getUnitaryPrice*2`

Pero no logro encontrar la forma de que multiplique el valor base (`unitaryPrice`) por el número que el usuario indique.

¿Debería replantearlo por completo? No entiendo si es que debo declarar el método `unitaryPrice` de algún otro modo para que me permita operar con él.

Comment: Tres cosas: 1) El método `getUnitaryPrice` está declarado como `void` y dices que retornas `unitaryPrice`, eso hará que no compile. 2) ¿Es necesario que sea estático? Quizás debas revisar el diseño o se trate de que el código está en una sola clase y lo pones estático para usarlo en el `public static void main(String[] args)`. 3) El switch con `getUnitaryPrice()` solamente no tiene sentido de por sí. Por favor provee el código relevante para comprender mejor el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respuesta:

Para que tu operación retorne un byte, debes hacer un casteo explícito:

```
return (byte)(unitaryPrice * 2);
```

---

Explicación

Más allá de los problemas de código que hay en tu pregunta, el problema está en este fragmento de código:

```
return unitaryPrice * 2;
```

El `2` es un valor literal, por lo cual se interpreta como si fuese una constante de tipo `int` tal como se explica en la [especificación del lenguaje](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type `int`.

Traducido a español:

> Un entero literal es de tipo `long` si se le aplica un sufijo con la letra ASCII `L` o `l` (ele); de lo contrario es de tipo `int`.

Y la multiplicación de un tipo `int` con un tipo `byte` produce como resultado un `int`, tal como se indica en [la especificación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2):

> The numerical operators, which result in a value of type `int` or `long`:
>
> (...)
>
> - The multiplicative operators `*`, `/`, and `%`

Traducido a español:

> Los operadores numéricos, que resultan en un valor de tipo `int` o `long`:
>
> (...)
>
> - Los operadores de multiplicación `*`, `/` y `%`.

Para que tu operación retorne un byte, debes hacer un casteo explícito:

```
return (byte)(unitaryPrice * 2);
```